# Is there a way to extract the calculation metadata from a pyspark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, metadata

I don't know if I'm using the right key terms in my question. My use-case here is as follows: I'm creating DataFrames in pyspark, and I'd love to be able to automate the documentation on how fields are calculated.

For Example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, "foo"),
        (2, "bar"),
    ],
    ["id", "label"]
)

df = df.withColumn('calc', f.col("id") + f.lit(1))
df = df.withColumn('calc', f.when(f.col('calc') > 1, 1).otherwise(0))
```

I've created a super simple DataFrame here with columns `"id"` and `"label"`, and added the calculated field `"calc"` based on a condition on the `"id"` field.

My understanding of Spark is that the calculations of the new field `"calc"` are cached and will be translated into a Spark SQL statement at time of execution when a function like `show()` or `collect()` are performed. I know this because when encountering errors using pyspark, the error message will show a SQL statement representing the field of issue, even if it was generated using pyspark syntax.

Is there a way for me to extract this underlying translated SQL statement showing the aggregate transformations performed on calculated fields?

I've been trying to search for this using the key term "calculation metadata" but have found no results. Either I'm using the incorrect term to search for the information I want, or what I'm looking to do is not feasible.

Comment: are you looking for this? `df.explain()
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [id#0L, label#1, CASE WHEN ((id#0L + 1) > 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS calc#17]
+- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[id#0L,label#1]`

Comment: Ref: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.explain.html